# find properties that has an attribute in a control

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes, custom-attributes

I have a page with a number of controls.

As the page is rendering I want to loop through all controls on the page and find any control that has a property with certain attribute. I am attempting to do this with c# - any ideas how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how big is your control tree. This is what I would do. I'm not promissing the best performance.

**Case 1.** Looking for .NET Attributes

```
IEnumerable<Control> GetMarkedControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
  foreach(Control c in controls)
  {
    var props = c.GetType().Properties();
    if(props.Count(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<YourAttribute>().Count() > 0) > 0)
      yield return c;

    foreach (Control ic in GetMarkedControls(c.Controls))
      yield return ic;
  }
}
```

**Case 2.** Looking for HTML attributes

```
IEnumerable<WebControl> GetMarkedControls(ControlCollection controls)
{
  foreach(Control c in controls)
  {
    if(c is WebControl)
    {
      var wc = c as WebControl;
      if (wc.Attributes.FirstOrDeafult(x => x.Name == "yourAttribute") != null)
        yield return c;
    }

    foreach (Control ic in GetMarkedControls(c.Controls))
      yield return ic;
  }
}
```

Now you can call it this way: `var controlsWAttribute = GetMarkedControls(this.Controls);` from your page or any control. This way you are not forced to call it at the page level.

With this method you explore the whole control tree in your page or control recursively.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Reflection 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx

using reflection you can get all the attributes of an object

Answer (score 0):

Every control that is on the page has a "controls" property which contains all of its children controls. I have written recursive functions to loop through these before but do not have any on hand. Let me try to write one real quick:

```
public Collection<Control> findControlsWithAttributes(Control startingControl)
{
    Collection<Control> toReturn = new Collection<Control>();
    foreach (Control curControl in startingControl.controls)
    {
        if (DO COMPARISON HERE WITH CURCONTROL) toReturn.add(curControl);
        if (curControl.Count() > 0) findControlsWithAttributes(curControl, toReturn);
    }
    return toReturn;
}

private void findControlsWithAttributes(Control startingControl, Collection<Control> inputCollection)
{
    foreach (Control curControl in startingControl.controls)
    {
        if (DO COMPARISON HERE WITH CURCONTROL) inputCollection.add(curControl);
        if (curControl.Count() > 0) findControlsWithAttributes(Control startingControl, Collection<Control> inputCollection);
    }
}
```

Its been a little while since i've done this and I can't remember off the top of my head if Collection.Count is a method or property so make sure you check that first, but if you pass the page in then this will check against every server-visible control on your page and return a collection containing controls that match your comparison.

Lastly, Control.Attributes will return an AttributeCollection which you should be able to subsequently compare against.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what attributes you are after but if class attributes is what you are after look to @user751975 other wise you can do something like ...

```
page.Controls.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl>().First().Attributes["class"]
```